# How can I bind a ListBox to a List AND bind an int?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, listbox

I have several ListBoxes on my Form and each corresponds to a List of doubles AND one int.

I need to use the int that corresponds to each in the click event of each respective ListBox.

So, I want the values in the listbox to correspond to the doubles in the List AND have an int attached to the listbox that I can use in a click event.

I thought about using an object made up of int and `List<double>` but I believe this will take away the bind functionality.

Can anyone suggest a way I can do this?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Tag` property of each `ListBox` to store the corresponding integer value. Sample code:

```
ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
List<double> doubleList = new List<double>() {1.0, 1.2, 1.3 };
int curInt = 1;
listBox1.DataSource = doubleList;
listBox1.Tag = curInt;
listBox1.Click +=new EventHandler(listBox_Click);

ListBox listBox2 = new ListBox();
doubleList = new List<double>() { 2.0, 2.2, 2.3 };
curInt = 2;
listBox2.DataSource = doubleList;
listBox2.Tag = curInt;
listBox2.Click += new EventHandler(listBox_Click);

this.Controls.Add(listBox1);
this.Controls.Add(listBox2);
```

Then you can easily get the corresponding int value in the `Click Event` method by doing something like:

```
private void listBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox curListBox = (ListBox)sender;
    int curInt = 0;
    if(curListBox.Tag != null) curInt = (int)curListBox.Tag;
}
```